# Google maps - bind click event to <a> tag inside infoBubble

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, onclicklistener, infobubble

I am trying to bind a click event to an  tag inside my infoBubble, unfotunatley I am having no luck at all. Here is my code and a few examples of what I have tried.

```
setTimeout(function () {

                    var options = {
                        zoom: 8,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(sonypro.locator.map.defaults.lat,sonypro.locator.map.defaults.lon),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }

                    sonypro.locator.map.view = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(sonypro.locator.selector_id.map),options);

                    sonypro.locator.map.panorama = sonypro.locator.map.view.getStreetView();

                    google.maps.event.addListener(sonypro.locator.map.panorama, 'visible_changed', function() {
                        if (sonypro.locator.map.panorama.getVisible()) {
                            if (!$('#'+sonypro.locator.selector_id.sidebar).hasClass('closed')) {
                                $('#'+sonypro.locator.selector_id.handle_btn).click();
                            }
                            $('#'+sonypro.locator.selector_id.sidebar).hide();
                        } else {
                            $('#'+sonypro.locator.selector_id.sidebar).show();
                            if ($('#'+sonypro.locator.selector_id.sidebar).hasClass('closed')) {
                                $('#'+sonypro.locator.selector_id.handle_btn).click();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    sonypro.locator.map.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                    if (sonypro.locator.map.dealers.length > 0) {


                        for (var i = 0; i < sonypro.locator.map.dealers.length; i++) {

                            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                                '/assets/images/content/markers/marker' + i + '.png',
                                new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                                new google.maps.Point(9, 26)
                            );

                            var dealer = sonypro.locator.map.dealers[i];

                            //info as html
                            var info_content = sonypro.locator.list.template(dealer.name,dealer.address,dealer.telephone,dealer.email,dealer.website);

                            //set markers
                            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dealer.lat, dealer.lng);
                            sonypro.locator.map.markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                                id: dealer.id,
                                position: myLatLng,
                                map: sonypro.locator.map.view,
                                icon: image,
                                shape: {coord: [1, 7, 9, 25, 16, 7, 13 , 3, 9 , 1, 4 , 3],type: 'poly'},
                                title: dealer.name,
                                info: info_content
                            });


                            //set infobubble
                            var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                                map: sonypro.locator.map.view,
                                content: '',
                                position: myLatLng,
                                shadowStyle: 0,
                                padding: 15,
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                                minWidth: 160,
                                maxWidth: 240,
                                minHeight: 80,
                                maxHeight: 300,
                                borderRadius: 0,
                                arrowSize: 10,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                borderColor: '#f36700',
                                disableAutoPan: true,
                                hideCloseButton: false,
                                arrowPosition: 18,
                                backgroundClassName: sonypro.locator.classes.infowindow,
                                arrowStyle: 0
                            });


                            //bounding
                            sonypro.locator.map.bounds.extend(myLatLng);
                            sonypro.locator.map.view.fitBounds(sonypro.locator.map.bounds);

                            //set infowindows
                            google.maps.event.addListener(sonypro.locator.map.markers[i], 'click', function () {
                                console.log('Something clicked');
                                var _lm = sonypro.locator.map.last_viewed_marker;
                                if (_lm == -1 || (_lm != -1 && _lm != this.id) || infoBubble.isOpen() == false) {
                                    infoBubble.content = this.info;
                                    infoBubble.open(sonypro.locator.map.view, this);
                                    sonypro.locator.map.view.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                                    sonypro.locator.map.last_viewed_marker = this.id;
                                }
                            });


                            $(infoBubble.bubble_).live("click", function() {
                                console.log('clicked!');
                            });


                            $(".icon.phne", infoBubble.bubble_).live("click", function() {
                              console.log('actived jimmy!');
                            });

                        }

                        sonypro.locator.list.init();

                    }

                }, 500);
```

Some of the above code might not be relevant and there is more than this but again not sure of all of it necessary but I can post all of it if necessary.

I've also tried using .live() and .on() to no avail.

Here is the template for the contents of the info bubble below. And the entire selector for the icon I am trying to bind a click event to is (`.pge-dl-engagement .dealer-wrapper .dealer-infowindow a.icon.phne`)

```
template: function (name,address,telephone,email,link) {
                var content = '',_name = '',_address = '',_telephone = '',_email = '',_link = '';
                if (!sonypro.helper.isEmpty(name)) _name = '<h3>'+name+'</h3>';
                if (!sonypro.helper.isEmpty(address)) _address = '<p>'+address+'</p><p class="display">'+telephone+'</p></div>';
                if (!sonypro.helper.isEmpty(telephone)) _telephone = '<div class="icons"><a class="icon phne"></a>';
                if (!sonypro.helper.isEmpty(email)) _email = '<a class="icon email" href="mailto:'+email+'"></a>';
                if (!sonypro.helper.isEmpty(link)) _link = '<a class="icon link" target="_blank" href="'+link+'"></a></div>';
                content = _name + _address + _telephone + _email + _link + '<div class="space cf">-</div>';
                sonypro.locator.list.html = sonypro.locator.list.html + '<li class="cf"><div class="dtls">' + content + '</li>';
                return content;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the solution, although it might be a bit different to what you might need:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(sonypro.locator.map.markers[i], 'click', function () {

//do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).on('click', '.email', function(e){...});` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still no luck with this suggestion. Any other ideas?